# Exporting war from Eclipse -- project created originally by IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

Our old dev team created a `Java / Tomcat / Maven` project in IntelliJ and sent it to us. I opened it in Eclipse using the `Existing Maven Projects` option. I can work on it and run it locally by running a `StreamProjectApplication` class which calls

```
SpringApplication.run(StreamProjectApplication.class, args);
```

from its `main` method.

But. Instead of the project name, Eclipse calls this app `stream_application`. And when I export a `war` the name stays as is, and when I try to reach the app from its address,

```
projectname/app/index.html
```

I get Tomcat's `The requested resource is not available.` error. Trying

```
stream_project/app/index.html
```

has the same error.

Again, locally when running on Tomcat through Eclipse the correct url, `projectname/app/index.html` works fine. But when deploying a `war` it does not.

What am I missing here? How can I export a `.war` file that can be deployed on `Tomcat` and reached with the correctly url?

Comment: You need to make up your mind how do you want to start this project via main method or by creating war file.

Comment: @AleksandrM By creating a war file.

Comment: Then create own and rename it to your needs.